# Additional .htaccess rules based on wp page

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I've created a page in the dashboard called Authors, created a new template-authors.php with completely own logic. It works well, going to website.com/authors/ I see a list of all authors, specifying the URL I can get to their details, for instance: `example.com/authors/?name=George`.
I can also switch profile pictures: `example.com/authors/?name=George&pic=1`, `example.com/authors/?name=George&pic=2` etc (default is 1).

I'm trying for half a day get user-friendly URLs been working but can't figure out a correct way... I'd like to achieve this kind of links: `example.com/authors/George` and `website.com/authors/George/2`.

Tried even a really basic code in the `functions.php`, but it doesn't work:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^qwerty', 'index.php/authors/', 'top');
```

`example.com/qwerty` displays 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have wrong "rewrite" parameter in your `add_rewrite_rule` call.

I'm writing it directly in here, so it can be buggy... But it should look something like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=<YOUR AUTHOR PAGE ID>&my_author_name=$matches[1]&my_author_pic=$matches[2]','top');
```

Then you can use `add_rewrite_tag` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) to add your custom query variables (`my_author_name` and `my_author_pic`).

And in your author page you should use these custom query variables.

Comment: It works! I had to change `'index.php/authors/?...'` to `'index.php?pagename=authors&...'`. Thx!

Comment: As I said your "rewrite" param was incorrect :)